# Is Spring Data OrientDB production-ready?

Tags: spring, spring-data, orientdb

I have a spring project and I would like very much to use Spring Data OrientDB,
is it production ready? or should I just use Graph API or blueprints?

Comment: The pom.xml shows that the module version is 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT. So I would say, it's not yet production ready.

Comment: Thanks man. and I guess you don't know anything about the current state of the project.

Comment: Well, in this case you better ask Oliver which edited your question and is the spring data project lead.

Comment: I would also add another option which is [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/gjrwebber/spring-data-gremlin) which beings Spring-Data and blueprints together so you could potentially use any blueprints database.

Comment: @karim Any updates on this? Because still, I can see the version 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT. If not, Are you using any other library?