# From using standard document/graph API to a JPA enabled framework on OrientDB

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, orientdb, gremlin

I have built a proof of concept for a webapp I've been working on for the last year. My app already has a well defined set of operations that are reused by the business to interact with orientDB. The interactions start from simple insert/queries to objects, to complex object inheritance creation, and new relationship types creation.

Right now I'm moving my POC Architecture to a formal model, and I want to migrate what I did using only the orientDB java API, to a more formal JPA model; So far I have checked the code and examples for spring-data-orientdb and spring-data-gremlin, which seems to provide a JPA approach. My question is the following; If my model has no more than 5 queries, does it make sense to add the JPA model? and also, from this jpa model, can I still have transactionality for direct db operations like new type of vertex creation among data insertions? has anybody has experienced the use of this API, their pros an cons?

I understand that both are still in dev ([Is Spring Data OrientDB production-ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744851/is-spring-data-orientdb-production-ready)) but want to know if anyone has any advice on where to move forward, or if it's better to wait until the projects are mature and keep working with document/graph API?